# How is an MVCCKey formed in CockroachDB?

Tags: rocksdb, cockroachdb

I want to create a MVCCKey with a timestamp and pretty value I know. But I realize a `roachpb.key` is not very straightforward; is there some prefix/suffix involved? Is the database name is also encoded in `roachpb.key`?

Can anyone please tell me how a MVCCKey is formed? What information does it have? In the documentation, it just says that it looks like /table/primary/key/column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`engine.MVCCKey`](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/22a06f5c41b9a0b23f9e262e3236e188f06b858c/storage/engine/mvcc.go#L84-L89) combines a regular key with a timestamp. `MVCCKeys` are [encoded](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/22a06f5c41b9a0b23f9e262e3236e188f06b858c/storage/engine/batch.go) into byte strings for use as RockDB keys (RocksDB is configured with a custom comparator so `MVCCKeys` are sorted correctly even though the timestamp uses a variable-width encoding).

Regular keys are byte strings of type [`roachpb.Key`](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/22a06f5c41b9a0b23f9e262e3236e188f06b858c/roachpb/data.go#L106-L108). For ordinary data records, the keys are [constructed](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/22a06f5c41b9a0b23f9e262e3236e188f06b858c/sql/sqlbase/structured.go) from table, column, and index IDs, along with the values of indexed columns. (The database ID is not included here; the database to which a table belongs can be found in the `system.descriptors` table)

The function [`keys.PrettyPrint`](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/22a06f5c41b9a0b23f9e262e3236e188f06b858c/keys/printer.go#L490) can convert a `roachpb.Key` to a human-readable form.